# Ios: How to pass data to a UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uisplitviewcontroller

So I have a simple setup where there is Single View application and when a button is pressed it changes the root view controller to display a SplitViewController.

Code below on how to do this:

```
 static NSString *TagForSplitViewController= @"SetupViewController";  


    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:TagForSplitViewController];
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIViewController *currentController = app.window.rootViewController;
    app.window.rootViewController = controller;
    app.window.rootViewController = currentController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view.window
                      duration:0.75
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{
                        app.window.rootViewController = controller;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
```

I now want to pass information (A String for example) from my single view to the split view controller so that it can display the text.

However I dont seem to be able to find a way to reference an instance of the SplitViewController (such as would be the way for a prepareBeforeSegue).

So how is it possible to get a reference on my SplitViewController instance and set some data ?

Should I somehow setup a delegate interface to do this ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "singleView.h"
```

in your SplitViewController.h. Then you can reference Strings or anything in your singleview.h.
But remember you should declare those variables which you use in both views in singleview.h

Comment: (have not tried it yet) but this sounds like its only feasable for static fields ? what about instance fields. I would still need to be given or passed the singleView instance in order to access those fields.

Comment: In your project can't you use static fields instead of instance fields? because you can't pass variables which you create & change inside a method. Only you can pass variables which you create in Interface & change in anywhere (inside methods).